# Codeigniter jQuery problem

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am building an application with codeigniter and I want to post some data using jQuery but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is the code what am I doing wrong ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?=site_url('requests/save')?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success:function(msg){
        alert(msg)
    }
});
```

I haven't written any code in the controller yet, just something simple to test it. Also as long as javascript is concerned that's about it. The ajax is trigered when the user clicks a button.

```
function save()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo 'ajax';
    }
    else
    {
        echo'sdfs';
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the output of this JS in your HTML? you are posting pre-outputed code which means you don't even know if the path shows up correctly.

Comment: Is the JS code running? Do you have any JavaScript errors in the console? Are you seeing an outgoing network request from your browser? If so, is CI running any code? What part of the process "isn't working"?

Comment: It does not output anything, the post does not happen. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.7indigo.gr/ci/index.php/requests/save. Origin http://7indigo.gr is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.this is the error I get.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Is it in one of your views? It would help to see code from all the associated files.

Comment: @Andre, he doesn't need XSS, his path is fine with `site_url('here/there');`. I suspect it is either a helper issue or controller issue (but I am making assumptions here without all the details)

Comment: @Jakub, I'm taking a shot a the dark also, but I had this problem before and found that I didn't have the crsf token in my post string

Comment: Is your JavaScript in a JS file or in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Dante,

First make sure you load your helper:

`$this->load->helper('url');`

Also post the JAVASCRIPT for us, not the PHP.  The Javascript is what is failing, not the CI PHP.  You might have a PHP issue also on your controller for `'requests/save'`, have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to pass a cross site request forgery token.

If you set XSS to true in your config, then your form helper creates a hidden field that is required to be passed to your server.

Make sure you are properly collecting your form data. Easiest to use jquery the .serialize() function.

Load the url helper in the autoload.php. Your url in the ajax call should just be 'requests/save'.

Also php shorthand echo tags are a bad practice stick to

```
<?php echo ?>
```

for better code portability

Moved my comment to an answer

Comment: It should `<?php echo 'something' ?>` without space, but yes this could be a problem, since `<?= 'something' ?>` will not work(or at least have an issue) with PHP 4.xx

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : to test the ajax, use the relative url instead use a php tag inline in your js, to your controller, which will work in any condition (in CI) whether you already removed the index.php from your url (using htaccess) or not by include the index.php in your url.

```
$.post('/index.php/request/save', { foo: 'bar' }, function (html) { 
   alert(html);
});
```

At targeted controller

```
function save()
{
   if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
   {
       echo $this->input->post('foo') ? $this->input->post('foo') : 'Not Bar';
   }
   else
   {
       echo'Not from AJAX';
   }

}
```

EDIT :
also make sure you have already load the url helper before using its function

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: This won't make a difference. Original question code and this answer would result in the same thing happening.

Comment: This is no different than what he is doing, he obviously did something wrong, or its outputting something not relevant to his target URL

Comment: In PHP4.x `<?=site_url('requests/save')?>` has some issues, so that separate the url as a variable is to ensure that he pointed to the right url (it can be debug easier).

Comment: @toopay, you are confusing Javascript with PHP, there is no such issue, as PHP never interacts with the JS code, its just providing output.  He shouldn't be using short-tags to begin with `<?=`

Comment: I will not concern the tag, if he didnt use php inline with his script. Look at his code. He try to declare a js variable from a php tag, and i suspect the `<?=site_url('requests/save')?>` didnt give him a correct url, thats why his ajax fails. Because if the url was correct, whatsoever result it can be from the targeted controller, it should echoed/alerted out. The ajax fails (i suspect) because the url is not pointed to the valid url.

Comment: The url is correct, when I write it on the browser it does point me to the correct file.

Comment: @Dante, By putting `<?=site_url('requests/save')?>` as your ajax parameter directly (without validate it first), then how do you know that the url is correct?

Comment: I take the parameter form the page source and put it on the browser address bar and it shows the correct file.

Comment: `I take the parameter form the page source and put it on the browser address bar and it shows the correct file` Well, that really not a good debugging method. But this reveals there should be something wrong in your requests controller. Also i've just notice you send the data parameter, did you validate that too?

Comment: @Dante. I was edited this answer 6 hours ago, instead using `url helper`(which can have several issues, especially with your php shorthand) i include the `index.php` inside the url at ajax parameter. Test it and see if it works (it work from my Ubuntu here).